# How to route egress traffic through operator gateway

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-networkpolicy, kubernetes-operator, kubernetes-networking

I have deployed [egress-operator](https://github.com/monzo/egress-operator#egress-operator) in my ubuntu machine and this operator is internally using [envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/) proxy to control egress traffic.

The idea is to allow only [whitelisted domains](https://github.com/monzo/egress-operator#usage) from test-pod for egress. I have applied the external service `yaml` of this operator but it's giving the opposite result, instead of allowing `google.com` its blocking google.com and allowing other calls. What possibly am I doing wrong?

**My ExternalService.yaml**

```
    apiVersion: egress.monzo.com/v1
    kind: ExternalService
    metadata:
      name: google
    spec:
      dnsName: google.com
      # optional, defaults to false, instructs dns server to rewrite queries for dnsName
      hijackDns: true
      ports:
      - port: 80
      - port: 443
        protocol: TCP
      minReplicas: 1
      maxReplicas: 3
```

**My testpod.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: testNs-system
  labels:
    egress.monzo.com/allowed-gateway: google
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx:1.14.2
    command:
      - "sleep"
      - "604800"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: nginx
  restartPolicy: Always
```

From testpod when `curl -v https://google.com` is blocking and other urls are allowed. As per operator's Readme, I need a [defaut-deny-Egress K3s policy also](https://github.com/monzo/egress-operator#blocking-non-gateway-traffic), therefore I applied that too. but after `default-deny-Egress` policy all egress calls including google.com (the one whitelisted) is blocking from testpod.

**Default-Deny-All-Egress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-all-egress
  namespace: testNs-system
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
      egress.monzo.com/allowed-gateway: google
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress: []
```

How can I route the egress traffic from the egress-operator pod or egress-operator gateway?

Comment: Not sure about `egress.monzo`, but this is possible to achieve using `istio egress`. Are you tight to any specific solution like `monzo`? Please refer to [istio egress - Accessing External Services](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-control/)

Comment: I am restrict to use opensource(free of cost) solutions. is istio free or paid/enterprise solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Posting this answer as a community wiki, feel free to edit and expand.

---

`Istio` can be used as a solution for this case. It's an open-source project so it doesn't require to pay for its usage.

Istio has a very good documentation with examples how to achieve different results. Documentation is much better for `istio` in comparison with `monzo` operator + a lot of big companies use it so it's reliable solution.

---

Accessing external services and whow it works:

> Because all outbound traffic from an Istio-enabled pod is redirected
> to its sidecar proxy by default, accessibility of URLs outside of the
> cluster depends on the configuration of the proxy. By default, Istio
> configures the Envoy proxy to pass through requests for unknown
> services. Although this provides a convenient way to get started with
> Istio, configuring stricter control is usually preferable.

Please find `istio` documentation and covered use cases with the same goal as yours:

- [Using egress control](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-control/)
- [Using egress gateway](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway/)